# Class member functions static and private

Tags: c++

Does it make sense to have some class member function say f() both private and static?
e.g.

```
class MyClass
{
 ...
private:

static int foo();
}
```

Thanks.

Hi thanks for all your comments! Ok, I got it. Yes, indeed initially I started using
static functions in my class because they were not related to the objects of my class-
were doing some other operations. Now I also realized they needn't be public.
So, I think I'll leave them like this.
I started to get some errors when I removed static keyword (apparently due to the way it was used throughout class, so I am lazy now to fix those, will just make it private and leave static :)).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. For example: private static member functions used for initialization or other purposes.

See this post for more information: [What is the use of private static member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445927/what-is-the-use-of-private-static-member-functions)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, sometimes. For example, utility functions used by the public static methods of the same class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, having a static private member function makes sense. It might, for example, be a stateless utility function used only by other members of the same class.

No, your class does not make sense. Since `MyClass` has no other members, no entity can ever see your `MyClass::foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Imagine a class that is purely static such as a statistical functions class. Helper functions may be private and static.

Answer (score 0):

of course. You might use it for internal purposes of your class, in private functions i.e.

```
class A{
    public:
        static int i_;
private:
    void privatef(){hiden_i_++;}
    static int hiden_i_;
};
```

Comment: Why don't you declare/define your functions as free functions in an anonymous namespace in the CPP file ?